# Having issues running pwsh shell in GitHub Actions with nektos/act locally

Tags: docker, debugging, github-actions, powershell-core

I'm super green to docker and looking for some troubleshooting direction for working with https://github.com/nektos/act.

I am able to successfully point to a workflow and run it and everything seems to be working as expected. The moment I add "pwsh" as the shell to run I receive the following failure message:

> docker exec cmd=[pwsh -command . /var/run/act/workflow/1.ps1] user= workdir=
> | OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "pwsh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
> [test-workflow/test_workflow_job]   ❌  Failure - RUN PWSH TEST

I'm not sure if it is a bug or not as there seems to be a previous and similar one that was resolved: https://github.com/nektos/act/pull/649/commits.

I'll be working to determine if this is indeed a different bug or if there is something blatant I'm missing.

Any direction is much appreciated!

Here is my github actions workflow:

```
name: test-workflow

on:
  push:
  
jobs:
  test_workflow_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

     - name: CHECKOUT THIS REPOSITORY
       uses: actions/checkout@v2

     - name: RUN PWSH TEST
       shell: pwsh
       run: Write-Host "test"
```

Comment: Are you also using WSL and therefore Docker for windows?

Comment: @MappaM sorry for the delay!!! Yes docker for Windows, not totally sure on wsl but I'm assuming so, will confirm

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue? Having same problem...

Comment: @epitka i have not had the time to dig back in so no resolutions from my end :(